# MongoDB aggregate via $in operator

Tags: mongodb

**posts**

```
> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e04"), "post_id" : 1, "user_id" : 1, "body" : "first", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e05"), "post_id" : 2, "user_id" : 1, "body" : "second", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e06"), "post_id" : 3, "user_id" : 2, "body" : "third", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e07"), "post_id" : 4, "user_id" : 3, "body" : "lalala", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e08"), "post_id" : 5, "user_id" : 4, "body" : "gogo", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de27fc60aab610f73e09"), "post_id" : 6, "user_id" : 5, "body" : "gogo", "is_block" : true }
```

**relationships**

```
> db.relationships.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22dd19fc60aab610f73e02"), "user_id" : 1, "target_user_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22dd1cfc60aab610f73e03"), "user_id" : 1, "target_user_id" : 3 }
```

I want to find `posts` that satisfied with below conditions.

1. `user_id` do not associated with `relationships`
2. `posts` that `is_block = false`
3. `posts` that do not self written

If viewers `user_id` is `1`, expected result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e08"), "post_id" : 5, "user_id" : 4, "body" : "gogo", "is_block" : false }
```

`post_id = 1` is self written post

`post_id = 2` is self written post

`post_id = 3` is associated with `relationships`

`post_id = 4` is associated with `relationships`

`post_id = 6` is `is_block = true`

It is equivalent with below mysql query.

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.user_id NOT IN
(
SELECT target_user_id FROM relationships WHERE user_id=1
)
```

How can I extract expected result via aggregate?

Is it possible on mongodb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation :

```
db.getCollection('posts').aggregate([{
    $match : {
        is_block : false,
        user_id : {$ne : 1}
    }
},{
    $lookup : {
        from : "relationships",
        as : "related",
        localField : "user_id",
        foreignField : "target_user_id"
    }
},{
    $match : {
        "related.user_id" : {$ne  : 1}
    }
}])
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple aggregation should suffice:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       $match: {
           $and: [
             { is_block: false},
             {"post_id" {$ne: "$user_id"}}
           ]
       }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "relationships",
            localField: "user_id",
            foreignField: "target_user_id",
            as: "match"
        }
    },
    {
       $match: {
          "match.0": {$exists: false}
       }
    }
])
```

Comment: It returned `post_id` 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are trying to do is use results from one query into another. MongoDB is designed for flat-documents and tightly coupled relationships need to be constructed carefully or avoided if possible.

What you can do is, in your program, run two queries since simple queries with use of index will be faster then aggregates.

Get `target_user_id` from `relationships` table:

```
var relatedUserIds = [1];    // since viewers user_id is 1
db.relationships.find({"user_id" : 1}).forEach(function(i) { relatedUserIds.push(i.target_user_id); })
```

User the result array in find query with `posts` collection:

```
db.posts.find({ 
    user_id : { $nin: relatedUserIds},
    is_block: false
    });
```

This will give you following results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d22de26fc60aab610f73e08"),
    "post_id" : 5,
    "user_id" : 4,
    "body" : "gogo",
    "is_block" : false
}
```

> To use this with large number of records, insert index on
>   `relationships.userId`,  `posts.userId` and `post.isBlock` to get faster
>   results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any method to use one query? I've already tried same with your answer before. But in my case, because of huge size of collections, it occured performance issue unless I triggered index properly.